# Seeking hints on how to explain w'(x) = D(x) for the inequality of...

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have an inequality

$$\frac{w(x+h) - w(x)}h \leq D(x)$$

How can I explain $w'(x) = D(x)$.

Does it have something to do with $h$ becoming really big or small?

$D(x)$ computes density for a given altitude $x$, and $w(x)$ computes the first few feet of pressure.

Please no answers, just some hints.

Thank you

Comment: Is this inequality true for all values of h? If so, recall the limit definition of the derivative.

Comment: Ok, I see that as h approaches 0, the limit is 1 for (w(x+h)−w(x))/h. So would that be equal to D(x)? Is 1 the rate of change for w(x)?

Answer (score 1):

The given inequality doesn't imply it, (my first idea was wrong)

For example take $\omega(x)\equiv 0$ and $D(x)\equiv 1$.
Than the given inequality holds for all $x$ but obvious $\omega'(x)\neq 1$

Comment: This was my thought as well, but it seems like the given inequality only implies $w'(x) \leq D(x)$

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Hi where is this chat?

Comment: at the top of the page there is at the right hand side of your name and of the review thing the word "chat" click on it to come to the chat